# Один исходный и исполняемый файл в MSVS 2010

Tags: visual-studio, c++

Можно ли в MSVC 2010 сделать так, чтобы создавалась не папка с кучей файлов, а один исходник с программой и исполняемый файл? Порой бесит - пишешь какую-нибудь маленькую программку, а создается куча каталогов (для меня это куча) и файлов. Можно ли как нибудь это исправить?

P.S. Пробовал создавать не проект, а файл, но он не компилируется. То есть при нажатии на F5 вообще ничего не происходит.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А что Вас так напрягает в таком большом количестве файлов? Вроде здесь всё как просто) Абстрагируйтесь от них и всё. Если вы работаете с этим проектом, то наверное удобнее просто открывать файл с расширением *.sln - это файл решения проекта, т. е. открыли его и про файлы в папке с проектом забыли - теперь они все у вас в окне VS в панели Solution Explorer. Да, там их ещё фигова туча, но никто ж вам не мешает создать в этой панели, или окне наверное правильнее говорить, новый фильтр и запихнуть туда все нужные вам файлы, а ненужные просто свернуть?
Да, и исполняемый файл лежит в папке Debug, после того как вы откомпилировали проект, или в папке Release, смотря какой режим компиляции вы выбираете!

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio создает те файлы, которые необходимы для ее работы. Особой избыточности в них нет. Чтобы включить в проект при создании файлы по минимуму, можно выставить опцию "пустой проект", а после создания удалить все кроме собственно файла проекта и добавленных файлов с исходными кодами.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать makefile. Тогда получается всего будет пять файлов:
 - исходник (cpp, h)
 - makefile
 из них будут получаться:
 - объектник (obj)
 - исполняемый файл (exe)

Правда, в таком случае использование такой тяжеловесной среды как VS2010 - стрельба из пушки по воробьям. Проблема в том, что нужно грамотно написать makefile и сконфигурировать среды для работы с ним.

Проекты из одного файла мне лично удобнее всего собирать с помощью gcc и сразу получать программу.

```
gaal@linux-lybs:~> g++ prog.cpp
gaal@linux-lybs:~> ./a.out
```

Еще неплохой вариант сделать все просто - использование утилиты BUILD из комплекта NTDDK. Она там используется для сборки драйверов и прикладных программ. Причем известно, что этой же утилитой пользуются при сборке самого дистрибутива Windows. Она весьма удобна и по сути своей является надстройкой над make.